# Difference between goroutines and boost.fiber

Tags: c++, boost, go, concurrency, goroutine

I just started having a look at go and how the concurency in go works.
I just wondered if you could implement something equal in C++ and found boost.fiber.
What's the difference between goroutines and boost fibers? 
Could you implement something goroutine like with those fibers in C++?

Comment: was going to go look at the code but couldn't find a submethod of boost called fiber. is it safe to assume that boost.fiber is the same as you meant? Just want to be sure before digging into source code.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean ... I am sorry

Comment: Here's (and outdated but valid for your question anyway) [description of how Go runtime works w.r.t goroutines](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) so you could compare and contrast by yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So from what I could gather from the source code of the boost.fiber library, it seems that it is indeed MUCH more versatile and powerful than goroutines. The mantra of goroutines is to not share data between the coroutines, but rather pass data into them as necessary. This is apparently possible within fibers as well with channels (`boost::fibers::unbounded_channel<T>` and `boost::fibers::bounded_channel<T>`), although one thing I'd keep in mind is data is safely shared between all fibers in a single thread. This is managed (by the use of mutexes, I guess) to ensure only one fiber runs at a time, so you may not need channels for a particular use case.

Fiber also seems to give you control over the synchronization of fibers within threads it seems. Apparently I/O that blocks will block an entire thread that the fiber running the operation is in, which makes sense. The cooler thing is that you could use Fiber to simulate blocking (e.g. for strict order of routine scheduling) if needed. There is a pretty good example of custom scheduling of fibers based on priority queuing here https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber/blob/master/examples/priority.cpp as well. However, I'd be willing to bet that scheduling defaults to interleaving them

So just to summarize, it seems the main points to take away are that yes, Fibers already has goroutine-like stuff already implemented. You have channels, you can multithread (and I'm sure this can be extended to multicore fun as well), and you can run async operations in the same thread (again, I'm assuming they default to interleaved scheduling in the same thread). Fibers seems to have much more, context-switching, fiber-safe shared memory, while go tends to keep things restricted to data passing using channels.

Honestly you'd have to surf the codebase a bit like I did to see what else Fibers has, but yeah I'd say these are some main diffs.

Comment: So, how does `boost.fiber` goes about implementing that "M × N" scheduling of goroutines where you have `N` OS threads serve `M` goroutines, with `N ≪ M`, allocating new threads only when there's the need for this?

Comment: Another point, is that without at least outlining how `boost.fiber` can be used to do [such](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) or [such](http://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and) stuff, your "...MUCH more versatile..." agitation appears to be a bit... uhm... uninformed. I mean, the fact Go has this stuff in its runtime and not in the form of an external library, has clear scientific background.

Comment: "this an advanced topic and should not be part of this lib. I'm working 
currently 
on a library implementing a thread-pool which uses internally fibers. 
It maps to a M:N solution. 
boost.fiber itself should provide only the low-level functionality (same as 
boost.context does 
for boost.coroutine and boost.coroutine acts for boost.fiber). 
the lib contains a unit-tests (test_migration) which shows how a fiber can 
be migrated 
between two threads (this code shows how work-stealing/work-sharing can be 
implemented in a thread-pool). " - Oliver Kowalke

Comment: You might be interested in studying [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10585505), [this](https://swtch.com/libtask/) and [this](http://state-threads.sourceforge.net/docs/st.html) to refine your research.

Comment: the reason it is much more versatile is because of how low-level it is. You can't change the scheduling in go for a single thread for instance. You can't share memory with goroutines, etc. etc. Just look at the source code and you can see this stuff. it's already out there. I'm obviously just generalizing to answer the OP's question concisely. no need to write a book for a simple and quick compare and contrast, ya know?

Comment: Of course, you can share memory with goroutines. It's just a suboptimal solution for many cases (which is sadly instilled in the brains of many folks coming from low-level languages). Channels can be thought of as queues protected by mutexes (though the implementation is more involved, of course). Channels allow you to write naturally flowing sequential code, but for those cases where it's more appropriate, there are mutexes, waitgroups, conditional variables and atomics. All this stuff.

Comment: you are right about that. I do need to change that. You can indeed share memory, though IIRC if your routine is scheduled across threads you need to be more safe about things

Comment: @CorvusCrypto, please take no offence, but from what you wrote I'd say you hardly wrote a working program in Go so I would advise the OP to actually do their own research.

Comment: changed it to be more clear that we are talking "safe" memory sharing. and yeah think back, without further implementing your own safe memory pools for multiple goroutine access, you can get race conditions. Boost::Fiber already takes care of this. And of course I take no offense, this is the whole point of discussing stuff like this.